# Xcode всплывающее меню подсказок

Tags: xcode

Всплывающее меню подсказок Xcode-а, рядом с функциями находится цветной буквенный символ - V, M, C, T и т.д. Что он означает?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно скриншот?

Answer (score 0):

C - class

M - method

T - type

V - variable

P - property

f - function

{} - code snippet

Ну и далее по аналогии